# How to create a DICOM directory faster?

Tags: directory, dicom, leadtools-sdk

I am crating DICOM directories with Leadtools SDK, everything is ok when the size of the study is not very much but when the study gets larger (eg. more than 4 or 5 gigs) it takes a lot of time to create the DICOM directory.
Is there any way to make the process faster ?

Answer (score 0):

In previous versions of LEADTOOLS, the time needed to create a Dicom directory grew at a large rate in proportion to the number of images.
In the latest version, the process has been greatly optimized and it is immensely faster, especially when the number of images is huge.

If your test data sets consist of a large number of images, we recommend downloading the latest version of the toolkit then contacting support@leadtools.com to obtain the latest optimized DLLs.
If the problem appears even when using a small number of images and with the latest DLLs, send full details to our support email address and we will investigate it further.